# Solving two very long equations simultaneously

Tags: equation-solving

I want to determine the zeros of two equations (the equations include only polynomials and fractions) simultaneously but the equations are really really long (more than 6 pages) and therefore NSolve doesn’t work. FindRoot is also not suitable since these equations have multiple solutions. Has anybody ideas what I can do to get all solutions?

Comment: It's hard to say without more information, but using `Compile` on your functions with `RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}` might make them amenable to being used in `NSolve`.

Comment: Can you calculate a [Gröbner basis](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroebnerBasis.html)?

Comment: _"...NSolve doesn’t work..."_ NSolve might not work because you haven't specified any constraints on the solutions. If you know some window like 0 < x < 100 where solutions might be, then it may work, but without your error message, it's hard to say why it isn't working for you.

Comment: If all numbers are exact and in terms of variables like $x$ and $y$ try `res=Resultant[poly1,poly2,y]`;  then `NSolve[res==0,x]` to obtain x component of zeros then substitute values of $x$ into say poly1 and NSolve to find associated value of $y$ like `NSolve[poly1==0/.x->x1,y]`

Comment: @flinty I have given it constraints. Furthermore, it doesn’t give me any error massage it just doesn’t finish.

Comment: Map `FindRoot` onto a list of the starting points: `FindRoot[eqns, {x, #}] & /@ {estimate1, estimate2, ...}`